# Möbius band deformation retracts onto core circle but not other interior circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> What is the intuition for why the mobius band deformation retracts onto its core circle but not, say, a boundary circle or some other interior circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the boundary, remember that the boundary of the Möbius band is one single circle; you can follow it all the way around the structure. If you tried to smoothly retract to it, you would have to either pull the band apart in the middle, or deform the boundary into a 'normal' circle, which cannot be done without making the band self-intersect.

To see the retract to the center circle, just reduce the width of the band until it collapses.

For the 'any other interior circle' question, any interior circle that is homotopic with the center can be retracted to, and any circle that is homotopic with the boundary cannot be retracted to.

Comment: Thanks this is helpful !